Internal storage goes missing and reappears after a few seconds
Whenever I use the media apps i.e gallery or any other app like file manager (the apps that require internal storage mostly), the apps close automatically after running like 5 seconds and upon reopening, the contents of app (the media/data that it was displaying) couldn't be found. I have to open them 2 to 3 times and clear it from memory using recent app button (not physical button). Than the contents i.e media show up and again disappear after few seconds and app closes.
Chrome runs fine as long as I'm browsing and abruptly closes within 5 seconds when a download is started. Same is in the case of YouTube reddit or any browsing app that I'm using. They [YouTube, reddit, chrome (when not downloading)] run fine for as long as I want.
Whatsapp throws an error saying "internal storage is missing" or "turn off USB storage" when downloading or uploading files but downloads media occasionally. Text messages don't throw any error. Just the downloadable files that require internal memory.
When I connect the phone to the PC via cable, the PC shows a number of internal storages, ranging from 1 to 20 or more. Depends upon the amount of duration that the phone was connected with PC. Firstly it shows 1 internal storage than keeps on showing more, having same information i.e 35 GB out of 109GB are free on every single one of them, with passage of time. Gallery will first show up as empty and after 1 or two seconds, show the media. The media is readable for few seconds and than the files will say "cannot generate thumbnail" or "cannot play video". I than clear the app from memory using recent apps button and again open it and clear it from memory 2/3 times. Than the media again shows up for 5/10 seconds and is perfectly readable or playable. If I don't clear it from memory, the media also comes back after 5 or 10 seconds and is playable for 5 to 10 seconds. LoL, looks like I'm writing same thing again and again. I don't want to rest until it's the only option (which it is). Infinix note 10 pro (X695), Android. Non rooted. No SD card is put in it.
I've tried everything that I could hear or read off. Clearing app cache using adb commands, clearing app data using abd commands (lost xhide data and was signed out of accounts due to this). Making a list of installed packages and using adb command to again install them for user 0. Installing third party virus scanning apps like Microsoft defender mobile (premium) and avast antivirus and avast cleaner app and CCleaner app etc etc etc to clear the hidden caches and scan for viruses. And probably everything that was not the solution for this issue.

What Android device(mode) and Android version does show this behavior? You may have problems with MediaStore database that is responsible for indexing files, provide file listings, thumbnails. You can try to clear the app data of MediaStore database system app . That will rest the index database (and start a re-index of all existent files) and hopefully fix the problems you have.

Safe mode is not present in Infinix note 10 pro non NFC variant. Device is on Android 11.

I'll try to clear that app. Would data be deleted or not? I don't want it to be deleted . Also, adb command to list all volumes ends up showing 3 volumes (1:emulated;999 unmountable none 2: private mounted none 3:emulated;0 mounted none) and anything that has to do something with emulated 999 or user 999 will end up in permission denied. I didn't create user 999. Can't clear it or mount or unmount it. I don't know if it's the solution. I'm saying this for additional information.

Media store database app was not listed in system apps. If it's package name is com.android.providers.media, than it's listed by package-name in my device and I've cleared it via clear cache and clear data options and nothing changed. Also via adb using clear command and rebooted. Same as it was. ಥ⁠_⁠ಥ

The media store database package name is often adapted by the manufacturer. On Google devices it is AFAIR com.google.android.providers.media.midule. On Samsung devices I have seen a similar name just with samsung instead of google. Clearing the database should not result in data loss as this database just stores the copy of the files meta data in a central place. Unless all files are reindexed some apps may not see all files (thus it may for a while look like files are missing).

I've cleared com.android.providers.media and com.android.providers.media.module but nothing changed. It's as if when the device has no storage, it will close any app that will open except the storage management settings despite the fact that almost 30 GB of internal storage is free. It actually started to happen when I got a low storage warning while downloading a large file. I uninstalled PUBG mobile and PUBG lite and freed up to 5 or 6 GB but it seems like something is stuck in that low storage mod. I also uninstalled some system apps like play services, play store, Google, gallery etc ◉⁠‿⁠◉

I used a sketchy app on PC to uninstall them. It uninstalled the app for user 0 which I think automatically triggered the system to make a backup of the system apps in another user profile 999 which is inaccessible. I couldn't find user 999 on the other devices when I ran command of listing all volumes and all users on those devices. They were someone else's devices and were not tampered with. Those system apps were reinstalled via command adb shell pm install-existing com.packagename which resulted in prompt saying "installed for user 0" as if they were already installed for user 999.

Removed user 999 and everything became tip top.
After struggling for 8 days on many platforms and going through so much stress, the final solution that worked was fairly simple.

install adb on your PC by watching a fairly popular video.
enable USB debugging in developer options
run command; adb shell list users (it will show you the users/user profiles currently active or running on your device).
If there are more than 1 users and both end with "running", you will have to remove 1 because it's the one revoking the permissions etc.
User 0 or UserInfo{0:name:number} is the main profile and is most likely that it's you. The other (UserInfo{999:name:number} in case of Infinix) is the secondary user profile that the system automatically made when you did something wrong like uninstalling a system app or a pre installed app that did not have the option to uninstall.
Simply use the adb command: adb shell pm remove-user 999
User 999 is not a universal user profile and your's might be different. It's the first number that comes after "UserInfo" if you run the first command.


Caution: I'm not a professional and neither do I claim that everything that I said is exactly what it is. I might be wrong about what user 999 is or about something else. All I'm saying is that it worked for me.

I didn't lose any of my data and every app is currently working fine.
